# how to return to menu after execution

Tags: python

**i'm new to python and tried out this program to include 6 conversions
the problems im facing are the function is being called again even after getting the answer
and also i tried out some methods but i cant seem to get to the first menu i.e select your choice of conversion menu also please correct me if i could simplify the code more and also if there are any errors**
*p.s-i know a little c,c++&java im really new to python ive just started recently*

```
 def f_c():
        foot=float(input('enter foot value'))
        cm=foot*30.48
        print(cm)
    def c_f():
        cm=float(input('enter centimeter value'))
        foot=cm/30.48
        print(foot)
    def km_mi():
        km=float(input('enter kilometers value'))
        mi=km*1.60934
        print(mi)
    def mi_km():
        mi=float(input('enter miles value'))
        km=mi/1.60934
        print(km)
    def ce_fa():
        ce= float(input("Enter temperature in celsius: "))
        fa=(ce * 9/5) + 32
        print(fa)
    def fa_ce():
        fa = float(input("Enter temperature in fahrenheit: "))
        ce = (fa - 32) * 5/9
        print(ce)
    print('conversions program')
    print('select your choice of conversion')
    print(' 1.foot-cm \n 2.kilometers-miles \n 3.celsius-farenheit')
    x=int(input('enter your choice'))
    print('selected choice %d'%x)
    while x<=3 and x>0 and True :
        if x==1 :
            print(' 1.foot to cm \n 2.cm to foot')
            a=int(input('select on of the above'))
            while a<=2 and a>0:
                if a==1:
                    f_c()
                    break
                else :
                    c_f()
                    break
        elif x==2:
            print(' 1.km to mi \n 2.mi to km')
            a=int(input('select on of the above'))
            while a<=2 and a>0:
                if a==1:
                    km_mi()
                    break
                else :
                    mi_km()
                    break
        else :
            print(' 1.c to f \n 2.f to c')
            a=int(input('select on of the above'))
            while a<=2 and a>0:
                if a==1:
                    ce_fa()
                    break
                else :
                    fa_ce()
                    break
        next_calculation = input("Let's do next calculation? (yes/no): ")
        if next_calculation == "no":
              break
        
        else:
            print("run program again")
```

Comment: `function is being called again even after getting the answer` which function?

Comment: can you once maybe run the program please!!??

Comment: is it still not solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what *@NiceOne* meant.

```
while True :
    print('conversions program')
    print('select your choice of conversion')
    print('1.foot-cm \n2.kilometers-miles\n3.celsius-farenheit')
    x=int(input('enter your choice: '))
    print('selected choice %d'%x)
    if x==1 :
        while True:
            print(' 1.foot to cm \n 2.cm to foot')
            a=int(input('select on of the above '))
            if a==1:
                f_c()
                break
            elif a==2:
                c_f()
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid input")
            
    elif x==2:
        while True:
            print(' 1.km to mi \n 2.mi to km')
            a=int(input('select on of the above'))
            if a==1:
                km_mi()
                break
            elif a==2 :
                mi_km()
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid input")
    elif x==3 :
        print(' 1.c to f \n 2.f to c')
        a=int(input('select on of the above'))
        while True:
            if a==1:
                ce_fa()
                break
            elif a==2 :
                fa_ce()
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid input")
    else:
        print("invalid input");
        continue
    next_calculation = input("Let's do next calculation? (yes/no): ")
    if next_calculation == "no":
        print("Exiting")
        break
    else:
        print("running program again")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the `menu` inside an infinite loop. And `break` when an exit condition is met.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I have'nt learnt about the python gui ,

Comment: maybe after learning ill try

Comment: @karthik___12345 it has nothing to do with gui.